# Doctrine batch processing

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, batch-processing

About batch processing. I have two objects, a Batch and a Element. Element has a ManyToOne relation to Batch. One batch contains about 10k elements. Each element must result in a sended email and Batch must be uptated realtime with the result of sending the email (+1 error or +1 success).
I want to iterate Element to avoid memory issue usign [this strategy](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html#iterating-results).  Can i detach every single Element after flush instead of clear the UoW to maintain persisted the Batch object?
In Element there's an onDelete="CASCADE" definition in Batch reference.

```
<?php
$batch = $em->getRepository('MyProject\Model\Batch')->find(1);
$q = $em->createQuery('select u from MyProject\Model\Element e WHERE e.batchId = '.$batch->getId());
$iterableResult = $q->iterate();
foreach ($iterableResult as $element) {
    // Sending email
    $result = $sendingObject->send($element);
    // Error 
    if($result === 0){
        $batch->increaseError();
    } else {
        $batch->increaseSuccess();
    }
    $em->flush(); // Executes all updates.
    $em->detach($element); // Detaches only element to keep $batch synchronized
}
```

Comment: sorry, don't fully get your question - why is there a need to flush per element? why do you want to detach each element?

Comment: @LBA because i have to iterate thousands of Element records and i have to update each record plus the Batch status... I cannot flush Batch and cascade Elements if they are 10 thousands because of memory issue.

Comment: where are you updating your $element in your example? within your 'send' method?

Comment: @LBA yes, some fields

Comment: then I rather suggest to not do it the ORM way but directly update your batch and elements with DQL - in this case I assume using ORM doesn't really help.